# Getting 2 Scatterplots and Histograms from a set of Data

Tags: r, graph, statistics, histogram, scatter-plot

so I have the following set of Data

```
> sleep
     extra group ID
1    0.7     1  1
2   -1.6     1  2
3   -0.2     1  3
4   -1.2     1  4
5   -0.1     1  5
6    3.4     1  6 
7    3.7     1  7
8    0.8     1  8
9    0.0     1  9
10   2.0     1 10
11   1.9     2  1
12   0.8     2  2
13   1.1     2  3
14   0.1     2  4
15  -0.1     2  5
16   4.4     2  6
17   5.5     2  7
18   1.6     2  8
19   4.6     2  9
20   3.4     2 10
```

My Task is to generate two Scatterplot that shows the effects of Drug 1 and 2(group) also two Histog, I've been using different things but seriously not clue and I cannot use ggplot as I'm not able to instal anything on my computer labs! Please help!.

Comment: `split` may be useful to you `par(mfrow = c(1,2)); sapply(split(sleep, sleep$group), function(x) with(x, plot(extra)))`

Comment: I still get Only 1 and I need to scatter plot showing Drug 1 and drug 2

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, maybe:

```
pdf("my_plots.pdf")
for (g in unique(sleep$group)) {
  with(sleep[sleep$group==g,], plot(ID, extra, main=paste0("Group = ",g)))
  hist(sleep$extra[sleep$group==g], main=paste0("Group = ",g))
}
dev.off()
```

Per @rawr's comment, you can also have two or four plots on a single page by adding `par(mfrow=c(1,2))` or `par(mfrow=c(2,2))` before running the code above.